# Problem on URL appearance in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, biber

My bibliography is appearing properly except by the fact that comes with some special symbols that were not suppose to appear, they're not on the main document.

Special characters appearing: these two symbols were not suppose to be there ¿ ¡

[image: Special characters appearing: these two symbols were not suppose to be there ¿ ¡]

Someone know how to take it out?

My .bib:

```
@online{inep_estabelece,
    title = {Estabelece as diretrizes e bases da educação nacional},
    url = {http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9394.htm},
    author = {{INEP}},
    urldate = {2020-12-06}
}
```

The packages:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\bibliography{references}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=abnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I added a lot of packages trying to solve it, but it continues appearing.

Thanks in advance for the help,

Comment: Hallo! If you can give a “minimal working example” (MWE) — ie not just the packages, but the source of a full compliance latex file, with just enough of your document preamble + content to demonstrate this problem — that will help us troubleshoot your issue. Help for writing a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: What happens if you (a) delete `\bibliography{references}`, (b) load the `url` package before rather than after the `hyperref` package, and (c) execute `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` -- and then perform a full recompile cycle?

Comment: @Mico, your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(repeating my earlier comment so that this posting may be considered to have received an "official" answer)

I suggest you

- delete `\bibliography{references}`,
- load the `url` package *before* rather than after the `hyperref` package, and
- execute `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Then, perform a full recompile cycle.

Answer (score -1):

As documentation the answer that solved my problem was answered by @Mico [Thanks a lot for the answer], in one of the comments. This is the current package list:

```
\include{include}
\include{packages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=abnt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Also this answer solved another problem that I was having, I don't know why exactly. kk

But this is for my theses at Brazil and we have specific rules to respect following "abnt" standards. Before the links wasn't appearing with the "<" or ">" symbols out of it and now this is happening finally. It's one of the rules of this standard I mentioned.

[image: Exampplify rules]

Thanks for the effort of those who answered! Have a great 2021!